# canvas.setBitmap(bitmap) works in emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I'm wanting to write a whiteboard app. I have a beginning that renders a bitmap (the drawing page) and then copies that bitmap to the surfaceView. It works perfectly in the emulator, but when I run it on my Samsung Galaxy Ace, it unexpectedly closes. This code:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
Log.d(TAG, "Create surface");           
mo_paper = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.paper);
Log.d(TAG, "Created paper");            
mo_easel = new Canvas();    
Log.d(TAG, "Created easel");            
mo_easel.setBitmap(mo_paper);
Log.d(TAG, "Set easel");            
mo_matrix = new Matrix();
Log.d(TAG, "Assets loaded");            
mainThread.setRunning(true);
mainThread.start();
Log.d(TAG, "Threads started");          
}
```

outputs 'Created easel' but not 'Set easel', so it appears the .setBitmap() method is causing the error.

Comment: What's the error exactly in ddms/logcat?

Comment: Also, how big (in pixels) is the bitmap?

Comment: @Peterdk - logcat just bombs. I don't understand how to use DDMS yet! ;)

Comment: @anterlsoft - just something like 400x300 pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmaps loaded from resources are immutable. You need to pass a BitmapFactory.Options that tell BitmapFactory that you want the resulting bitmap to be immutable.

Comment: Okay. I've traced through and found that in the emulator the bitmap is loaded as mutable, but on the phone it isn't. The app also works on an HTC Desire-Z, so it seems to be an OS difference. I should have said I'm running 2.3.3 on phone and emulator, API level 10.

However, I cannot find how to set the bitmap to inMutable...checking docs, I see inMutable is API 11 onwards. Googling suggests I need to write a method to transform a bitmap, like this - http://sudarnimalan.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/android-convert-immutable-bitmap-into.html

Comment: "*resulting bitmap to be immutable*" should be "*resulting bitmap to be* **mutable**" ?

Answer (score 0):

Romain Guy was correct. On the phone the bitmap was being loaded as immutable, but in the emulator and on another phone, it was being loaded as mutable (contrary to the documentation!). Setting the option inMutable isn't possible on API's before 11, so in my case, the simple solution was to create an empty bitmap with

```
    mo_paper = Bitmap.createBitmap(paperWidth, paperHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

and just draw on whatever other bitmaps I want